# –removeInitialMenu... methods on properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa-touch

While coding I came across something I did not notice before in Cocoa. For every property next to get and set methods (by default) multiple remove methods are added as wel.

For example when I have the following class:

```
@interface MenuScene : UIView

@property CGRect initalMenuFrame;

@end
```

The following methods are added to my MenuScene (next to the default getters and setters).

[image: Remove Methods]

I have Googled around and I can't seem to find documentation about this (perhaps I am using the wrong keywords) but I am curious.

Answer (score 1):

Those methods are not really added.

The **code completion** proposes a couple of methods containing your property name including get*, replace*, remove*, insert*, intersect*, add* and set*.

For example it also suggest this get* method:
[image]

i think the reason for such a code completion might be **to teach you to use consistent method naming** so always use `remove` instead of `delete` and `add` instead of `append`, etc.

See also this entry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922647/what-is-the-idea-purpose-of-xcode-suggesting-these-method-names-based-on-propert

Comment: Really there is no `get*` as the getters don't have the prefix of `get` so it would just be `*`.

Comment: we are talking about methods with parameters not getters. i.e. take a look at [`[NSString getCharacters:range:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/getCharacters:range:)

Comment: The compiler would never proposer a method name for a property with `get` in it and it the `set` is auto-generated by the compiler as a setter. The link you have just linked me to are method names, if you see any method with the word `get` before it than it has been added by the developer, `get` is not normally used in objective-c. So no it wouldn't propose a method name with `get` in it that is wrong. If you are going to tell me to look at a document that is huge than you need to be telling me where to look. `getCharacters:range:` is a method declared by the developer not the compiler.

Comment: **Code Completion is done by the IDE not the compiler**. Nobody talked about a compiler!


I am deeply sorry that my link to the **official Apple Documentation** did not work perfectly and you had to type "getCharacters:" in a search bar to see it, what a pain it must have been.


Yes [NSString getCharacters:range:] is written by a developer, but by one that had probably to follow **strict and consistent API naming guidelines**.


**Please try to be constructive** and recreate what @Matthijn did, then you will see that indeed the Xcode Code Completion does suggest a method starting with `get`.

Comment: Right so what does that link have to do with anything since at your own admission that will have been created by the developer? You seem to have a little bit of an attitude when someone questions your answer. Have a read of some actual documentation that says not to use `get` https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html.

Comment: From that document `If the method returns an attribute of the receiver, name the method after the attribute. The use of “get” is unnecessary, unless one or more values are returned indirectly.` And the only time you should use `get` `Use “get” only for methods that return objects and values indirectly. You should use this form for methods only when multiple items need to be returned.` So when the user has a property like that they shouldn't be using `get`.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the code completion to my answer with the suggested `get` method, in which the values would be returned indirectly, which is - as you wrote - the only time you should use get.

Comment: +1 for adding the image. I may have misunderstood your answer. Sorry. I do believe though the documentation that I have provided and the bit about returns objects and values indirectly could greatly improve your answer. May I recommend adding it to your answer and referencing the documentation.

Comment: I would consider it rather off topic. I am not even 100% sure that my answer is correct. I actually hoped for other answers with different ideas.

Comment: Well either way it was my misunderstanding of what you meant. I have left my comments though as it was generally a good discussion.